# UEFI doesn't recognize HDD for EFI boot

Tags: boot, uefi

I bought an SSD and have an HDD with Ubuntu and Windows 10, moving the Windows OS partition to the SSD, deleting it from the HDD; upon doing this, UEFI doesn't see the HDD, even after disabling CSM boot:

- I don't know for what reason I decided GRUB2 was broken, but I repaired it successfully by following this [tutorial](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd); I had to mount the EFI partition additionally, as it's on a separate partition, but this didn't help.
- Executing `/usr/sbin/blkid` from Linux Live USB returns: *(LiveUSB: `sda` | SSD : `sdb`)*

  ```
  /dev/sda1: LABEL="XUBUNTU 20_" UUID="F252-C0D0" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0aa71107-01"
  /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
  /dev/sdb1: UUID="D8E4-5A1E" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b93a3217-731b-489f-a68e-283e2cc10bff"
  /dev/sdb2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="6c8431e8-8f2a-4f1f-910e-f179507f9d7c"
  /dev/sdb3: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="EEEEE76FEEE72E91" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="88088879-98ad-4de2-9c75-6cedfa4116bf"
  /dev/sdb4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="38A6EC92A6EC5244" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="9e8294e6-30fa-4b48-b841-1a39ba91a0b1"
  /dev/sdc1: UUID="7E31-57E6" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="625dc62c-b40a-498e-aa67-31ed4da3edfd"
  /dev/sdc2: UUID="eeeb811d-b8b4-4b72-a3f3-f49d02e10fea" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="62f795d0-ba0e-4be1-b74b-cf85d5473538"
  ```
- I can mount Ubuntu [`/dev/sdc2`] and the EFI partition [`/dev/sdc1`] on `/mnt`:

  ```
  lsblk
    NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    loop0    7:0    0   1.5G  1 loop /rofs

    sda      8:0    1   7.2G  0 disk
    └─sda1   8:1    1   7.2G  0 part /cdrom

    sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
    ├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part
    ├─sdb2   8:18   0    16M  0 part
    ├─sdb3   8:19   0 465.2G  0 part
    └─sdb4   8:20   0   499M  0 part

    sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
    ├─sdc1   8:33   0   512M  0 part /mnt/boot/efi
    └─sdc2   8:34   0 634.9G  0 part /mnt
  ```

  ```
  ls /mnt
    bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  swapfile  sys  tmp  usr  var

  ls /mnt/boot
    config-5.4.0-26-generic  efi  grub  initrd.img  initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic  initrd.img.old  System.map-5.4.0-26-generic  vmlinuz  vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic

  ls /mnt/boot/efi/EFI/
    BOOT  Microsoft  ubuntu

  ls /mnt/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
    BOOTX64.CSV  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi
  ```

How do I find where the problem is? *(I can easily solve the problem by reinstalling Ubuntu on `/dev/sdc`, but I want to know what the issue is.)*

Comment: UEFI and BIOS are not the same things - it's one or the other _(you have UEFI)_.  if you're referring to the UEFI bootloader not seeing the HDD _(not the same as the UEFI firmware not recognizing the drive)_, this would occur if the UEFI bootloader doesn't detect an EFI bootable OS from the drive or an EFI bootable OS was installed, but CSM mode was enabled in the UEFI firmware [emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture]. Was Ubuntu installed as EFI bootable? If so, ensure CSM mode is disabled and troubleshoot via Ubuntu's documentation for troubleshooting EFI boot issues.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't see the HD"?